# What does "principle" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of *principle* in this definition of *soul* from [Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/soul).com as in *body and soul*?

> the principle of life, feeling, thought, and action in humans, regarded as a distinct entity separate from the body, and commonly held to be separable in existence from the body; the spiritual part of humans as distinct from the physical part.

Does *principle* in this context mean definition #7 of Google definition or does it mean something else that's not in this dictionary?

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'd go with #7.

Comment: Yup, 7 is correct.

Comment: 6 isn't far away, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I could see #'s 6, 7 and 8 applying to the definition of "principle" as it relates to a component of a soul.  It's more the context of the example that drives my answer, not just the definitions in abstract.